# AzureDevops Agent doesn't list capabilities for VS2019

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I've AzureDevOps 2019.1.1, and I have Agent version 2.153.1 for Builds and have Visual Studio 2019 installed, however the agent doesn't list the VisualStudio capabilities and hence the VS build doesn't get the agents assigned. Any help on why the agents does not list the capabilities automatically, would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Agent (as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#capabilities)?

Answer (score 2):

If you install agent first and then VS2019, you need to restart the agent for new capability to show up in the pool.

If you install VS2019 first then agent and still not listed vs2019, you can search `CapabilityFunctions.ps1` in the search box of your computer. The code show the function of detecting capabilities.

[image]

In addition ,as a workaround , you can manually add them as user-defined capabilities and then check if they can run as normal.

[image]

You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/615994/azure-devops-server-2019-build-agents-do-not-disco.html) with the same issue.

Comment: Thank you Hugh. I did everything which is provided in the reference it was no help. Then figured out that if I install x86 version of the agent it lists the capabilites but not for x64 agent version. I re-verified I have x64 OS and VS, not sure why the agent needs to be x86. Please clarify this if you know. Thank you!